# sequencing things in document class Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I just recently switched from doing timeline code to documentclass and I am having some trouble figuring this out...

I am making a choice based game so I have a lot of choices that needs to take place...

in the time line what I did was had each frame with choice. if the user picked a choice it would assign that choice a variable and at the end of the game it would run a switch case to pick out the one with that variable and adds it to the screen...

but as soon as I got to the document class to try to do the same things just using code; I couldn't figure out what to do...

I mean i couldn't operate it the same way, otherwise I would have if loops with in if loops with in if loops and I would have to write down each possibility manually. so I decided to use the bitmap screenshots instead but now I can't figure out...that how do I exactly sequence things inside the document class?...I mean how do I tell it to show me these choice after the previous ones are done? and not have to gointo never ending if loops. with timeline I was able to sequence things using frames but without accessing frames how can I sequence things based on, if a choice is clicked, remove those objects and add new ones but not getting locked within functions of functions? can somebody show me the light by providing a clear example please? I am really new at this and really lost,too...

Comment: You best start - and I really don't mean to be condescending - by learning about object-oriented programming, especially about handling data.  I can only assume that your game is a common multiple choice type of question-and-answer template - in which case you can express all of your question and answers in a neat data structure built from a bunch of `Dictionary` objects.  This is quite simple, and it requires only a few lines of code - but you won't understand it, unless you first learn about collections, iterations (and possibly recursion).

Comment: I realize this is not the answer you were hoping for, that's why I made it a comment. But do yourself a favor: You have some very powerful tools at your disposal. Invest some time into learning how to use them properly - both you and your projects will benefit greatly.

Comment: BTW adding and removing stuff from the stage (or any other `DisplayObjectContainer`) is done via `addChild()`and `removeChild()`.